# django-db2 use different schema name than database username

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, db2

In Django database username is used as schema name.

In DB2 there is no database level users. OS users will be used for login into the database.

In my database I have two different names for database user and database schema.
So in django with db2 as backend how can I use different schema name to access the tables?

EDIT:
Clarifying that I'm trying to access via the ORM and not raw SQLs. The ORM implicitly is using the username as the schema name. How do I avoid that ?

Answer (score 0):

DB2 uses so-called two part names, `schemaname.objectname`. Each object, including tables, can be referenced by the entire name. Within a session there is the current schema which by default is set to the username. It can be changed by the `SET SCHEMA myschema` statement.

For your question there are two options:
1) Reference the tables with their full name: `schemaname.tablename`
2) Use `set schema` to set the common schemaname and reference just the table.

Comment: Where should I add "SET SCHEMA myschema"? While accessing models how can we use different schema names, since by default it will be used as username.model_name?

Comment: Also I want to access default django tables(eg. tables used for auth) to be accessed from different schema name than database user.

Comment: Thanks Henrik, How do we ask the ORM to use a different schema?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution for this:

1) We can use following query to change the schema in db2:

```
set schema schema_name;
```

2) We can execute above query at django startup.
We have to add following code in any of urls.py, manage.py files which will run it on startup.

```
def set_schema(sender, **kwargs):
    from django.db import connection
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute("set schema schema_name")
    except Exception as e:
        print str(e)

from django.db.backends.signals import connection_created
connection_created.connect(set_schema)
```

Comment: What do the **kwargs means?

Comment: Also, I have added to the manage.py and it is still likely going to the username schema.