# Django DB2 with Multiple Schemas

Tags: python, django, db2

I would like to know whether it is possible for the Python(3.8.10)-Django(3.2) to connect to the DB2 with multiple schemas.

Currently, I am using the settings similar to the example in the GitHub

```
DATABASES = {
      'default': {
         'ENGINE'     : 'ibm_db_django',
         'NAME'       : 'mydb',
         'USER'       : 'db2inst1',
         'PASSWORD'   : 'ibmdb2',
         'HOST'       : 'localhost',
         'PORT'       : '50000',
         'PCONNECT'   :  True,      #Optional property, default is false
      },
     'MYSCHEMA': {
         'ENGINE'     : 'ibm_db_django',
         'NAME'       : 'mydb',
         'USER'       : 'db2inst1',
         'PASSWORD'   : 'ibmdb2',
         'HOST'       : 'localhost',
         'PORT'       : '50000',          
         ‘SCHEMA’      : ‘MYSCEHMA’,  # no error for adding the ‘SCHEMA’ parameter (or not) until running
         'PCONNECT'   :  True,      #Optional property, default is false

   }
```

However, it is using db2inst1 as the default schema.  Is it possible to use other schema?  For instance, I am using MYSCHEMA for the application.
For the above settings, I am not sure what I could fill the schema name in the DATABASE variables.

I have added in corresponding coding:
`SomeModel.objects.using(‘MYSCHEMA’).all()  #The default is to use the “default” database connection.`

Once it is running in the Django, it will show db2inst1.tabname is an undefined name.  (Table willing to use: MYSCHEMA.tabname)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159706/django-db2-use-different-schema-name-than-database-username